# "/.ssh/config line 1: no argument after keyword "w" " error

Tags: bash, git, ssh

I'm trying to clone a repository from git through SSH and keep geeting this error

`/.ssh/config line 1: no argument after keyword "w"`

[image]

I tried changing my config file

```
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_hub
```

but it made no difference. I seem to have set up the ssh key properly, but can't make it work.

I tried using wsl and bash

Comment: Maybe it's an encoding issue?

Comment: If you could edit the output of `xxd /c/Users/cpinh/.ssh/config` into the question (ideally as text rather than a screenshot), that would let us rule out (or confirm) some theories.

Comment: (BTW, what's your `HOME` variable set to in the above transcript? Is it `//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/caroltavares`, or is it `/c/Users/cpinh`? And do you know if you're invoking a Windows-native SSH executable or a WSL one?)

Answer (score -2):

Try pointing it to a specific directory were to drop the file: `git clone git@github:payfy/admin-tools.git /path/to/directory`

If you'd like it to drop at the current directory, a dot (.) will suffice.

Comment: Can't possibly be the problem: The OP's error message is coming from the transport layer (in this case, ssh itself), which has nothing to do with where git is being told to put the files.